# Expose OpenCV C++ Mat to Python

Tags: python, c++, boost

Hello everyone basically i have the following

A test.cpp as it follows

```
cv::Mat load(string filename){

Mat img = imread(filename,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
GpuMat cudaMat;
cudaMat.upload(img);
cuda::DeviceInfo deviceinfo;
cout << "GPU: "<< deviceinfo.cuda::DeviceInfo::name() << endl;   
imshow("opencvtest_load",img);
waitKey(0);
return img;
}
```

and i'm wrapping with boost as it follows:

```
#include<boost/python.hpp>
using namespace boost::python;
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(opencvtest)
{
def("load",load);
}
```

I generate everythong with the make command To be called from python code test.py

```
image = "some directory and image"
from opencvtest import load
img3 = load(image)
```

So, in fact what i need now is to get that Mat from the load method to be processed converted to python.

At the time i have the following error: 
    TypeError: No to_python (by-value) converter found for C++ type:
    cv::Mat

So i'm done with all the libraries solutions because they trow errors all the time. Is there a better solution for this. Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: I'll probably get flamed for this but you use Modern C and you want to step down to python? It's like having an Audi or Mercedes and replacing it with a T-Ford ...

Comment: The fact is all the required libraries i need are already in python i only speed up part of my algorithm using C++ and CUDA and i need the ouput from this  ti be "received" by python

Comment: Please elaborate: Why python in the first place if you want speed? python is an interpreted language and thus not a smart choice if you want speed

Answer (score 0):

Long story short: in order to use Boost with a C++ class, you need to expose the C++ methods to Python as well.

Python's memory management strategy is very different from C++'s, so in order for an object to be managed by both, you need to wrap the C++ class in a Python-friendly wrapper. Boost has functions to facilitate this, though I haven't checked exactly how to do this and Boost's documentation isn't amazing for the Python library. Check [this part of Boost's python documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/python/doc/html/tutorial/tutorial/exposing.html) for how to do it.

If you want to use OpenCV in both C++ and Python, it's a little more complicated than it sounds. Even though OpenCV has both C++ and Python bindings, the Python bindings all use NumPy whereas the C++ bindings use classes such as `cv::Mat`. In order to use them together, you'll have to deal with converting to and from those formats.

However, that conversion can be made a little simpler, since Boost also has NumPy array bindings (which means that the conversion can be handled entirely in C++). I found [this](https://gist.github.com/aFewThings/c79e124f649ea9928bfc7bb8827f1a1c) bit of code that helped me handle the rather confusing conversions, and found that even with an HD image the overhead of converting was minimal (since it's mostly `memcpy`).

And as for the comment of "why use Python if you have C++ available"- development time of C++ can be slow, especially when dealing with image processing. Python may be slow, but the development time can be much, much faster. If you've written working Python code and want to speed it up, it can be easier to convert pieces of it to C++ than to start rewriting it entirely.